# Biholomorphic map between the upper half plane with a slit and the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathbb{H} = \{z\in \mathbb{C}| \ Im(z) > 0 \}$.

I want to find a biholomorphic mapping between $\Omega_{} = \mathbb{H}-\{it \ | \ t \leq 1 \}$ and $D(0,1)$.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to use the function $\Phi_1(z)=z^2$
Then $\Phi_{1}(\Omega) = \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant-1}$
You now translate everything to the right by using $\Phi_2(z)=z+1$
Applying now $\Phi_1^{-1}(z)$ to get back to $\mathbb{H}$ and finally the Cayley function to map $\mathbb{H}$ to $D(0,1)$
The whole function is therefore $\Phi(z)=\frac{\sqrt{z^2+1}-i}{\sqrt{z^2+1}+i}$
It is clearly biholomorphic :-)